# Hiding the text with dots and showing it up on mouseover

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am displaying application names on page load. If the application name is too big i want to show it partially with dots and want to display the full application name on mousehover. I am trying to do it but not getting the exact solution. Can anybody help me in this.
I am using asp.net 4.0 with jquery.

Thanks
Asma

Comment: "I am trying to do it but not getting the exact solution" And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried doing it with the "title" property of span tag but it didnt workout.

Answer (score 2):

Use like following

```
<span title="long name">long...</span>
```

Use the `title` to display the full name. On mouse over it display's

If u want to style the tooltip use the following plugin.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Answer (score 0):

you can generate html like this

```
<li class="someclass" data-short="app..." data-full="application">app...</li>
```

assuming you use li tag and so jq code will be

```
$(function () {
    $(".someclass").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).data('full'));
    });
    $(".someclass").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).data('short'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use substring function of string class and title attribute of that control

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- make sure you have the jquery library loaded !-->

<div class="application_name">My Long Application Name</div>
<div class="application_name">My Long Application Name</div>
<div class="application_name">My Long Application Name</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // on page load

    var max_characters = 10;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // iterate all application names

        $('.application_name').each(function(){

            // establish if they contain more than your desired number of characters

            if($(this).html().length > max_characters){

                // attach nesting divs to the DOM to work with later

                var html = '';

                html += '<div class="long_application_name" style="display:none;">';
                html += $(this).html();
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div class="short_application_name">'
                html += $(this).html().substring(0, max_characters) + '...';
                html += '</div>';

                $(this).html(html);

            }

            $(this).mouseover(function(){

                // show hide the appropriate nested divs

                $(this).find('.long_application_name').show();
                $(this).find('.short_application_name').hide();

            })

            $(this).mouseout(function(){

                // show hide the appropriate nested divs

                $(this).find('.long_application_name').hide();
                $(this).find('.short_application_name').show();

            })
        })
    });

</script>
```